# Trying to new a ContextFactory in Program > public static void Main

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I've tried to slim the code down here to focus on what I think to be the missing piece.

This is the "public static void Main(string[] args)" method of a console application.

As it's static I have to new-up the creditService and inject the Repository.

I just can't figure out how to create the financeRepository "IContextFactory< IFinanceContext > contextFactory" - I've left the expected input signature in the code below for explanation.

I've been going round in circles with this for days.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IFinanceContext financeContext = new FinanceContext();
    IFinanceRepository financeRepository = financeContext(IContextFactory<IFinanceContext> contextFactory);

    ICreditService creditService = new CreditService(financeRepository);
    CreditHandler _creditHandler = new CreditHandler(creditService);

    _creditHandler.Handle();
}
```

Elsewhere in the solution, in another project, Ninject bootstraps it like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IContextFactory<IFinanceContext>>().ToFactory();
kernel.Bind<IFinanceContext>().To<FinanceContext>();
```

then where needed it's injected in via the constructor.
So am I completely off base trying to new-up the Repository when there's a way to inject it in? I presumed I couldn't do that with a static method. 
Please help!

Comment: Line 4 - I left it in to demonstrate the expected input parameter

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. If you are using Ninject you shouldn't have to instantiate ("new-up") the repository, it should be automatically injected by Ninject, you just need to tell it where. Please see this: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/How-Injection-Works

Comment: When I try to inject it in I get the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, reference or property contextFactory"

contextFactory being the name of factory I'm trying to create/use/new-up

Comment: From your code it seems like you don't know how to apply IOC containers. The concept of configuring the container at startup (Main method...) and then using it to resolve services, best case 1 Type holding the entire object hierarchy, that's a general concept applying to all DI containers. It's not a ninject specific issue. You should read up on that.

Comment: BatteryBckupUnit, that is exactly the case. You've channeled me in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Ninject.Extensions.Factory? It seems it fits very well for your needs. 
It is very powerful tool but the basics are very simple, you can browse the documentation which is great.

Here some resources to get started with :

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface

http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/31/ninject-extensions-factory-introduction/

Comment: Thank you for the info, much appreciated